# How to increase font size for Urdu Language?

Tags: mojave, font

I am using the Urdu language on Mac OS Mojave and it appears very small. I have no issue with the English text. Is there any way to increase it?

Just to clarify, I am talking about the Urdu text I see on web page or written in Word document etc.

Answer (score 1):

In a Word document (or any other similar text) you just select the text and then go to the area where it gives the name of the font and the size and change the size.

For a web browser you probably  have to use the zoom function (View > Zoom In for Safari).

Urdu is no different than any other language as far as increasing the font size is concerned.